# Catastophic failure of Ubuntu 18.04 when playing any videos

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, graphics, video, crash

Within minutes of playing any videos in any browser my whole system hangs and the only thing I can do to recover it is to do a hard reset by pressing the power button.
Sometimes I still have the use of a mouse for a minute, then it freezes on screen. Sometimes the audio is in a tight loop repeating over and over again.
Keyboard is dead so I cannot kill or soft reboot system.

I have researched my problem and looked at many questions with similar problems, also bug reports and my own log files to try to figure out what is going wrong but to no avail. (Too many cryptic messages for me to understand!)

I first thought it might be a microcode file issue, so I updated that but the date on the file is always updated to 2010-09-28. Seems old to me.

Then I have tried different graphic drivers. I am now using:
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

All this has failed to resolve the Catastrophe failure of My System when ever I playing videos in a browser. (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Vivaldi)

---

## Memory at reboot of My System

Every 5.0s: free -m 6

MySystem : Mon Jul 29 12:31:50 2019

Vars:  total      used     free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:   3752       1904     568       69      1280         1540
Swap:  7627       0        7627

---

## Microcode:

This seems to be a very old update! I have tried to update this file many
different ways, but it is always the same update version.

dmesg | grep microcode

[    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0xa0b, date = 2010-09-28
[    0.030880] MDS: Vulnerable: Clear CPU buffers attempted, no microcode
[    1.243117] microcode: sig=0x1067a, pf=0x10, revision=0xa0b
[    1.243185] microcode: Microcode Update Driver: v2.2.

---

## My processor

cat /proc/cpuinfo

processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 23
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Quad CPU    Q8200  @ 2.33GHz
stepping    : 10
microcode   : 0xa0b
cpu MHz     : 2005.075
cache size  : 2048 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti dtherm
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds
bogomips    : 4678.51
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

---

## My Ubuntu System

inxi -F

System:    Host: Computer-One Kernel: 4.15.0-55-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Machine:   Device: desktop Mobo: MSI model: P43 Neo-F (MS-7519) v: 1.0

serial:    N/A

BIOS:      American Megatrends v: V1.12 date: 01/18/2010

CPU:       Quad core Intel Core2 Quad Q8200 (-MCP-)

```
       cache: 2048 KB
       clock speeds: 
       max: 2336 MHz 
       1: 2005 MHz 
       2: 2005 MHz 
       3: 2005 MHz
       4: 2005 MHz
```

Graphics:  Card: NVIDIA G94 [GeForce 9600 GT]

```
       Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 )

       drivers: nvidia (unloaded: modesetting,fbdev,vesa,nouveau)

       Resolution: 1360x768@60.02hz

       OpenGL: renderer: GeForce 9600 GT/PCIe/SSE2

       version: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 340.107
```

Audio:     Card-1 Intel 82801JI (ICH10 Family) HD Audio Controller
           driver: snd_hda_intel

```
       Card-2 C-Media Audio Adapter (Planet UP-100 Genius G-Talk)
       driver: USB Audio

       Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-55-generic
```

Network:   Card: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169

```
       IF: enp4s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full

       mac: 00:21:85:5c:73:50
```

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2000.4GB (18.8% used)

```
       ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST2000DM006 size: 2000.4GB
```

Partition: 
           ID-1: / size: 39G used: 27G (73%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5

```
       ID-2: /boot size: 961M used: 147M (17%) fs: ext2 dev: /dev/sda1

       ID-3: /home size: 1.8T used: 317G (19%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7

       ID-4: swap-1 size: 8.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%)

       fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
```

RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present

Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 34.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 36C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A

Info:      Processes: 340 Uptime: 18 min Memory: 2046.4/3752.6MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56

---

## When loading app this error occurs

nvidia-settings

(nvidia-settings:5839): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:37:36.539: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at either
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-340.107-key-documentation
       or /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** (nvidia-settings:5839): WARNING **: 12:37:36.853: PRIME: Failed to execute child process “/usr/bin/prime-supported” (No such file or directory)
** Message: 12:37:36.853: PRIME: is it supported? no

---

Thanks in advice for any help or advice.

Comment: It would be a better read if you remove anything from the question that is not related to the video card. " Within minutes of playing any videos in any browser my whole system hangs and the only thing I can do to recover it is to do a hard reset "  did you memtest the memory modules? Total lockups tend to be hardware error. Not software. And a broken memory module often is the main culprit.

Comment: I have now tested the memory with memtest86+ for the last 10 hours and made 9 passes without any errors in them. So I do not think it is the memory.